# Monitoring average buffer content from interval variables using docplex.cp

Tags: scheduling, cp, docplex

I have a job-shop model programmed using CPO (docplex.cp) and it is working fine! I have model all my scheduling variables as interval variables like ops(j,o) and mops(j, o, m) (job, operation, machine) like in the cp doc examples.

However, I have inserted some machines as buffers, which are optional and no-fixed sized. The objective of the optimization is set to minimize Makespan, but I would like to add a KPI monitoring the number of buffers used in parallel at each moment to get the maximum and the average.

I have delved into the docplex examples and documentation but I have no idea on how to this. My vague attempts have revolved around creating a step _at(0,) variable and accumulating pulse(mops), but I don't know how to extract the "max" of it. Any idea or suggestion?

I can provide the code, but it is very similar to the one in the documentation.

Comment: In the jobshop problem, an operation has to be executed on a given machine. So it is not clear what you mean by inserting a "machine as buffer".

Comment: Dear @OlivierLhomme, thanks for your response and asnwer. I have modelled a Job Shop considering limited buffer capacity and, in doing so, I have modelled these buffers as extra machines in intermediate stages with no fixed duration. Therefore, I would like monitor the number of "machines" (buffers) used at the same time, getting the max number.

Comment: What I can deduce from your question: the jobs and machines stay as in a normal jobshop, but some additional machines, called buffers, can be used. They are optional. And they are not always working but can be run or stopped as needed. And you want to have the max number of simultaneously active buffers. Is it right? A given operation of a job must be executed on a given machine, say m5. What help can be expected from a buffer wrt this operation? any buffer can replace machine m5? Only the buffer b5 can replace the machine m5? There are several buffer b5?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explained myself properly. Buffers are introduced as optional non-fixed machines to handle cases where consecutive operations can't be directly chained. Jobs have consecutive operations and, from a Lean perspective, if two consecutive operations cannot be chained, buffers are use for the time needed. So, if there are 3 ops per job, then there are 3 machine stages, and 2 buffer stages (1-2, 2-3) to hold the jobs when they are not in a machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's clearer now. You could:

1. Create an optional interval variable buffer_i_j for each job i between each operation j and operation j+1, and constrain it to start at end of operation j, and to end at start of operation j+1.
2. Add a constraint so that buffer_i_j is present if and only if its length is different from 0.
3. Then introduce a cumul expression f, so that all the buffers contribute to f by a pulse of height 1.
4. Then it remains to get the max of f. There is no direct way, but you can do as follows.

let MAX be the max capacity of f, the number of jobs can be used for that.

Let HORIZON be an interval variable starting at 0 and ending at the max possible time in your problem.

Let us introduce `g = pulse(HORIZON,0,MAX)`

Add the constaint `f+g<=MAX`

Define `f_max = MAX - heightAtStart(g,HORIZON)`

Now if we maximize f_max, it will be the max level of f on HORIZON

You need to put f_max in your objective.

Comment: Thank you for your perspective. I've encountered a similar approach in another post, but having it thoroughly explained here is beneficial. However, my emphasis is that the buffer content shouldn't be the primary objective but rather a Key Performance Indicator (KPI) to be monitored, preventing the necessity of resorting to simulation for deeper analysis. Alternatively, it could be integrated into a weighted objective function, along with other relevant factors.... is there the possibility to do this?